# Highlight things marked as obsolete

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I recently did some refactoring in our code and marked some widely-used functions as obsolete. The problem now is, that I get not visual indicator when I use an obsolete function right away. I have to hover over the function call to get the popup with further information about that function, and even there the "deprecated" warning is not very prominent. As these functions are to widely-used and cause no real treat, setting the `isError` property is not an option.

I know that somewhere I saw obsolete functions that were highlighted with some kind of underlining, but I can not find an option that does that. Where is that option, or how else can I achieve a more eye-catching indication?

Comment: Marking `<Obsolete()>` on a class will make it's constructor be underlined with a green line (MSVS '17). Aside from that is it possible the highlighting you recall was the use a third-party tool such as ReSharper?

Comment: @Toby I tried marking `<Obsolete()>` on a class, and there was no highlighting anywhere. I also tried with `<Obsolete("[MESSAGE]", True)`, which worked just fine and underlined every usage with a red line (but setting `isError` is not an option, like I said).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have created a simple toy VB.Net console application in MSVS, as you can see in the image the items marked obsolete are underlined in green where they are used.

If you are not seeing this then you will need to provide some more details on your solution's settings - what type of project is it, what version of visual studio are you opening it in, is it the same version it was created in, do you have any third party code linter (eg ReSharper) in use... etc

[image: demonstrates underlining in very small toy console application]

**EDIT:** As you mention in your comment, the project's properties, including the Code Analysis settings, will affect whether this underlining show's correctly or not; you will need to ensure the correct rule-set is selected there.

Comment: I found it! It was a wrong rule set in the "Code Analysis" section of the project's properties. As you pointed me into that direction, it would be fair to accept your answer, but only if you included the solution in you answer. I'm not sure what happens if I edited your answer to include it, so as soon as you edit your answer to include this, I'll accept it. Thanks!